# Camera caption in android, how to set title on top of the screen of camera

Tags: android, camera

In my app I use camera.
For my goal I have to print title on top of the camera.

I call camera with

```
Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, mPictureFileUri);
startActivityForResult(intent, GlobalProps.REQUEST_PHOTO);
```

On top of the screen I want to show the Title, so that user will figure out how the camera has to be rotated.

How can I put title on top of the screen of camera?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The method you're using to call camera does actually open the Device's default camera App, and the camera app doesn't have any label itself. Thus you can't do change it's UI.

For custom Camera UI, you need to create a separate activity in your app itself, which will directly stream data from the camera to your activity, without opening the default camera app. Check [the official tutorial](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media/camera.html#custom-camera) on this. This way you can modify your UI, in whatever way you want.